# PowerShell issue with string -match

Tags: string, powershell, match

I need to match a content of a string against set of strings. I have something like this:

```
>$ID = "GEt"
>$ID -Match  "Get|YES|NO"
True
```

I don't need `-cmatch` - that's alright. But the following - not:

```
>$ID = "targetService"
>$ID -Match  "Get|YES|NO"
True
```

How do I avoid that, if the string I'm looking for is a substring of another?

Comment: `"get","yes","no" -contains $ID`

Comment: Issue? No! This is REGEEEEEX! Seriously, you should read a little about regex and matches in powershell.

Answer (score 2):

You can force an exact match with an alternating regex by adding the begin and end line anchors (^ and $).  Use a non-capturing group to isolate the alternated text from the anchors:

```
$ID = "targetService"
$ID -Match  '^(?:Get|YES|NO)$'

False
```

Answer (score 1):

As [indicated in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38267461/powershell-issue-with-string-match/38270190#comment63954361_38267461), a regex `-match` operation is not necessary when you're looking for an exact match among a set of strings. Simply use the [`-contains` operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx) (or `-in` in PowerShell 3.0+):

```
PS C:\> $ID = "GEt"
PS C:\> $Options = "get","yes","no"
PS C:\> $Options -contains $ID
True
PS C:\> $ID -in $Options
True
PS C:\> $ID = "targetService"
PS C:\> $Options -contains $ID
False
```